# How to get retuned value from one laravel route into another route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to get value of one route into another

```
Route::get('/first_url', function () {
   return "Hello this is test";
});
```

I Tried something like this but not worked.

```
Route::get('/second_url', function () {
   $other_view = Redirect::to('first_url');
});
```

I want to get returned value from `first_url` to variable `$other_view` in `second_url` to process and manipulate returned value.

Using Redirect is changing url. Which I dont want to use.

Any Idea ??? Or Am I trying wrong thing to do.

Comment: Do you just want to redirect to 'first_url' when someone goes to 'second _url'? If not, can you give more details please.

Comment: you should definitely give more details... otherwise @AlexeyMezenin s answer is the one you should rely to. ( But we can only guess )

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin , I want to get returned value from first_url to variable $other_view in second url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to return `first_url`, do this:

```
Route::get('/first_url', ['as' => 'firstRoute', function () {
    return "Hello this is test";
}]);

Route::get('/second_url', function () {
    return redirect()->route('firstRoute');
});
```

Learn more about redirects to routes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects).

**Update:**

If you want to pass variable, you can use form or just create a link with parameters. You can try something like this `{{ route('second_url', ['param' => 1]) }}`

Then your second route will look like this:

```
Route::get('/second_url/{param}', ['uses' => 'MyController@myMethod', 'param' => 'param']);
```

And `myMethod` method in `MyController`:

```
public function myMethod($param){
    echo $param;
...
```

Comment: I have added more info in my question, please kindly have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would like to do this, but you can get the rendered contents of the route by executing a simple HTTP request to your route and reading the contents:

```
Route::get('/second_url', function () {
   $other_view = file_get_contents(URL::to('first_url'));

   return $other_view; // Outputs whatever 'first_url' renders
});
```

Comment: I want to generate a pdf after getting html from another url, Otherwise I needed to recode to make that html form for pdf. So I was trying to just get html of one route url into another.

Comment: This depends on how you want to generate the PDF, but this solution should be perfectly fine for you. If you're using controllers for your routes, then there's a way to get the rendered contents of another route by invoking the target controller method manually. Maybe off-topic, but for best results I'd recommend using a CLI tool like http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ to generate the PDFs, because it uses WebKit to render the target page. Generating the PDF is then as simple as calling `wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/first_url /path/to/output.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send HTTP request and then process the response. You can use file_get_contents as @tommy has suggested or you can use HTTP library like Guzzle:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get(route('firstRoute'));
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case u should use a named route.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes

somthing like this:

```
Route::get('/first_url', ['as' => 'nameOfRoute', function () {
    return "Hello this is test";
}]);

Route::get('/second_url', function () {
    redirect()->route('nameOfRoute');
});
```

Comment: I have added more info in my question, please kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass the variable value to another route directly. http is stateless protocol. if you want to preserve the value of variable to another route you can do that by 3 methods query string, sessions and cookies only. Your can pass parameter to to specific route like this

> Route::get('/second_url/{param}', ['uses' => 'MyController@myMethod',
>   'param' => 'param']);

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind achieving what you want is naming the function of your first route and calling it within both the first route and your second route. Your function will simply return the view to the first route, and retrieve the rendered html for your second.

```
function MyFirstRouteFunction() {
    // Do whatever your do in your first route
    // I assume your function return here an instance of Laravel's View
}

Route::get('/first_url', MyFirstRouteFunction);

Route::get('/second_url', function () {
    $contentsOfFirstRoute = MyFirstRouteFunction()->render();

    // Make use of rendered HTML
});
```

There is no need to make one extra HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Guzzle or curl to achive this:

```
Route::get('/second_url', function () {

    //:::::Guzzle example:::::
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(); 
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'http://...second_url...', []);

    //:::::curl example:::::    
    $ch = curl_init();

    //define options
    $optArray = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://...second_url...',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
    //apply those options
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);

    //execute request and get response
    $res = curl_exec($ch);

});
```

Note that using Guzzle may need you to install required libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your first_route closure into a controller action you could try to instantiate that controller and call the method directly.

This is considered as bad practice.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/first_url', 'TestController@getFirstUrl');
```

App/Http/Controllers/TestController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function getFirstUrl()
    {
        return view('my-view');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/second_url', function () {
    $controller = new \App\Http\Controllers\TestController();
    $contentsOfFirstRoute = $controller->getFirstRoute();

    // Make use of rendered HTML
});
```